# How can I use str.join() instead of "+=" to join a list of strings with separator?

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

I have some code which is essentially this:

```
data = ["some", "data", "lots", "of", "strings"]
separator = "."

output_string = ""
for datum in data:
    output_string += datum + separator
```

How can I do this with `str.join()` or a similar built-in function?

Comment: `output_string = ".".join(data)`

Comment: The title is confusing.  How is this different from how `str.join` is normally used?

Comment: I don't see "multiple iterables interleaving" here

Comment: Yep, I was confused about str.join(). Sorry.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If the separator is a variable you can just use  `variable.join(iterable)`:

```
data = ["some", "data", "lots", "of", "strings"]
separator = "."


print(separator.join(data))
some.data.lots.of.strings
```

Answer (score 6):

```
output_string = ".".join(data)
```

if you have integers or non-strings in data, then

```
output_string = ".".join( str(x) for x in data )
```