# Adding a character between the whitespaces of a multiple word string

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a function that takes in an undetermined amount of parameters, which are the words, that will add a "+" between the single words. At the end it should still be a string.

```
def add_words(word1 word2 word3 ...)
```

output:

```
"word1+word2+word3 ...")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919680/can-a-variable-number-of-arguments-be-passed-to-a-function
and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33270019/python-3-str-join-with-seperator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method of strings and [argument expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745952/how-to-expand-a-list-to-function-arguments-in-python) to do this!

```py
def add_words(*words):
    return "+".join(words)
```

```py
>>> add_words("foo", "bar", "baz")
'foo+bar+baz'
```

Note that the `.join()` method is actually being used from the string `"+"`, rather than the argument words

Comment: It's a bit different from what I wanted to do but still helped me out. I didn't have the words split up in different stings and just had a full sentence so I wrote a function for that and then used your solution. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Excellent! If you already have some char and not a collection, you may be able to replace 'em directly with [`.replace()` or a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65801481/how-to-add-suffix-to-a-plain-text-in-python), or speculating, perhaps you're really looking for URL encoding https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode (which will handle special characters too)